# Where is the right place for beautifying values from the DB for the user view?

Tags: sql, angularjs, spring

What I mean by this question is this :

Lets say I have a WEB App (Spring, AngularJS, Oracle/MySQL). I select from the DB two columns which will represant an interval for example : "age_from" and "age_to". My purpose is to display thouse two values lets say "18" and "21" in the client view as "18 - 21".

So there are many ways to do it but I wonder between thouse two:

1. Select them like this from DB :  `"select (age_from|| ' - ' || age_to) as age_interval, ..."` and store the String value into my backend object as an attribute : `String ageInterval;` and after I pass the Object(which contains that field) to the client side I can use "ageInterval" to display the interval to the client.
2. I can select the two columns from the DB and store their values into different fields into my Object like : `Double ageFrom; Double ageTo;` (I store the double values in case 1 also) and after I pass the Object to the client side there I can use some JS logic to create a String like " ageFrom - ageTo " or directly display them like this into the HTML :

   `<div> {{myObject.ageFrom}} - {{myObject.ageTo}} </div>` .

So the main question is where shoud be the logic for creating the beautify view (String in our case: "18 - 21") which we will be displayed to the user (in the HTML). Server or Client side or DB select ?

Comment: #2.  Always the presentation layer, never the data layer.

Comment: Never DB. Preferably Client View. One of MVC principles is that Model shouldn't be involved in any presentation details.

Comment: right, better if server side won't know anything about the way we are going to use the data. so use angular instead of db to format the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a key word in your question title that should help you decide: "beautifying".  When you see something like that, always think "presentation layer".  Leave the data access layer to what it does best: deal with raw data.  Always format your data for display in the presentation layer.  Thus, prefer your #2 over your #1.

Answer (score 1):

To add an example of why you should put the "beautification" in presentation layer:

Let's say you then decide that you would rather like to print it like `18 to 21 years` - which layer should change if such modification is needed? A layer that's responsible for data retrieval or the layer that's responsible for it's presentation?

And then - suppose you decide you want to add internationalization to your app and so you now want the text around "18" and "21" to depend on the language chosen by the user - in which layer that should be dealt with?